# saving new category programmatically with setPath

Tags: category, programmatically

Now this is the sort of problem I would help others with but I am flummoxed. 
I am creating new categories in an import routine, e.g.

```
$this->magObject = Mage::getModel("catalog/category");
$this->magObject->setName($item["name"]);
$this->magObject->setData("agilityId",$item["id"]);
$this->magObject->setIsActive($this->isActive);
$this->magObject->setIsAnchor($this->isAnchor);
$this->magObject->setPageLayout($this->pageLayout);
$this->magObject->setStoreId(Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)); 
//$this->magObject->setPath ("1/2/6") ); //actually got by getting path of specific required parent
$this->magObject->save();
```

Without the setPath it saves fine, but with the wrong path (obviously).  When the setPath is included, nothing happens.  I know that there are devious magento elements at work that prevent writing to _entity tables unless certain circumstances are met but I thought I was meeting them .   I am already performing the usual

```
define("ADMIN_STORE_ID",1);
//...
Mage::app();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
```

at the start but in this instance it just is not working.  I have similar scripts on other sites that do work.  Only difference with this site is that there are multiple store fronts

```
3 UK
7 Spanish
5 German
6 French
1 Default Store View
```

Anyone spot something obvious that I am missing, whilst I still have some hair left?

Oh this is using Magento 1.9.1.1.

Comment: Oddly though, I can set the attributeSetId....which works and is still in the entity table

Comment: ->setParentId(6) does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to set the path. This is calculated based on the parent.  Same goes for the level.
Instead you should set the parent id.

So you can do this:

```
$this->magObject = Mage::getModel("catalog/category");
$this->magObject->setName($item["name"]);
$this->magObject->setData("agilityId",$item["id"]);
$this->magObject->setIsActive($this->isActive);
$this->magObject->setIsAnchor($this->isAnchor);
$this->magObject->setPageLayout($this->pageLayout);
$this->magObject->setStoreId(Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)); 
$this->magObject->setParentId(2);
$this->magObject->save();
```

Comment: I have tried setParentId(6)  and that has the same non effect, it comes out as 0 and the path is just the id of the new cat

Comment: on other sites I have successfully used ->setPath(#PARENT PATH#)  but they were version 1.9.0.1 - wonder if there is a difference there

Comment: I have managed to get around the problem my doing

    $this->magObject->move(6,null); 

but that doesn't really explain why it doesn't work in the first place